# Clash with identifier 'clock' from time.h

Tags: c++, g++, clang

The following program

```
#include <ctime>

struct clock {};

int main() {
    clock c;
}
```

fails to compile on both g++ 5.4 and clang 3.8 (Ubuntu 64-bit).

### g++ output

```
clock.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
clock.cpp:6:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
    clock c;
          ^
```

### clang output

```
clock.cpp:6:5: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'clock' in this scope
    clock c;
    ^
    struct 
/usr/include/time.h:189:16: note: struct 'clock' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'clock' here
extern clock_t clock (void) __THROW;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

The diagnostics vary a little in form, but are related to the same issue. There is a clash with the standard C function `clock` and the struct of the same name defined in the program. The relevant declaration from `time.h`:

```
extern clock_t clock (void) __THROW;
```

The question is: shouldn't such symbols be in the `std` namespace, since the program includes `<ctime>`? Interestingly, that very declaration sits a couple of lines after a macro which reads `__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD`. In addition, in `<ctime>`, one can see:

```
namespace std
{
    using ::clock_t;
    using ::time_t;
    using ::tm;

    using ::clock;
    ...
}
```

Is there some kind of bug here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is: shouldn't such symbols be in the `std` namespace...

Yes, and they are. Unfortunately, the C++ standard also allows implementations to put names from C-library derived headers in the global namespace. In this case, you get `std::clock` *and* `::clock`.

This applies to all the `<c*>` C++ headers with a corresponding `<*.h>` version in C.

Comment: You are right that that's unfortunate. I would add that to the list of inconveniences C++ programmers have to put up with in the name of _C compatibility_. Do you think there's any hope the standard could be changed to require that those symbols be *only* available in the `std` namespace? Thank you.

Comment: @Zunino - no, that won't happen. That was required back in the olden days, and nobody implemented it that way:, too much to maintain. The change to allow C names in the global namespace reflects reality. Put `clock` in your own namespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, that's just too bad. I'm probably missing stuff here, but why can't it be something more clear-cut, such as: use C header files if you want to have symbols in the global namespace; use the C++ counterparts if you want to have them neatly placed in the `std` one. The user would then get what they asked for.

In its current state, it's not only messy but also misleading. A C++ program inadvertently using a symbol such as `clock` could suddenly break if the user decided to, say, include `<map>`, which might indirectly include `time.h`. It doesn't look right. Thanks.

Comment: @Zunino - again, put `clock` in your namespace. That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right. Preceding the identifier in the example program with `struct` also seems to be another way around it. However, my point was not so much about how to solve the problem, but about how this and other similar situations can baffle and drive away new (and not so new) C++ programmers. Stroustrup himself has long been advocating for ridding the language of inconsistencies and unnecessary complexities, with the aim to make it more friendly to novices, which I see as a noble goal. Disclaimer: I'm not implying you disagree; I just wanted to try and explain my point.